# enabled and disabled button with select picker react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, isenabled

when the select value is equal to the first select = 'please select' i want to disable the button and enable it the inverse when i select.

```
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);


const handleChangeButton =() => { 
setDisabled(false);
}
const getctg2 = (val) => { 
if (val !="please select "){
handleChangeButton();
}

}
```

the error msg that i have is : ***Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.***

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

const getctg2 = (val) => {
  setDisabled( val =="please select" );
}
```

Comment: i must setDisabled to false ! i try it your proposition the same error message ...

Comment: @Garrix Please share your complete code